# Spring Boot: load all beans implementing an interface in test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have some interface `Filter` and some implementations of this interface.

In `@Test`, I'd like to load all beans implementing `Filter`.

Currently, I have to declare them explicitly. For example:

`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {FilterA.class, FilterB.class})`

The problem: Introducing another `Filter` would require adding it for each test class that uses the `filters`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `TestConfiguration` and declare all the beans implementing the interface in the configuration. Then add an `@Import(TestConfiguration.class)` in your tests.

That way if there is an extra implementation you only add it in the `TestConfiguration`.

Only thing you need to take care of is adding the appropriate implementation of the interface with use of the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: by writing methods annotated with `@Bean` and returning a `new` object?

Comment: Yes exactly. Make sure you annotate your class with @TestConfiguration. This will mark it a test configuration class instead of a regular configuration class and therefore will not interfere with your bean setup in your application.